# what does to word 'crete' mean in English?

Tags: meaning, suffixes, prefixes, roots

In my native language, words are created using `'Root Words'` + `'Prefixes/suffixes'`.
Also the root words make sense for us.

**Is English the same?**

For example I think the word `'crete'` is the root and `'dis,con & ...'` are its prefixes creating the words `'concrete'` or `'discrete'`. And does the word `'crete'` have meaning related to the meaning of the words `'concrete'` or `'discrete'`?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you look up the etymology of _concrete_, you will see that it is stated to have appeared in the English lexis as a direct import from Latin _concretus_. This means that there may very well not be an English word _crete_ (although see [Definitions.com_crete](https://www.definitions.net/definition/Crete)). Even if the common noun exists, it may have arisen separately. Word formation is not totally predictable. What does your research show?

Comment: You are asking about etymology. Did you try the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com)?

Comment: Please note that EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because in my native language the meaning of the root words is almost the same as the whole word [roots + prefix/suffix], it helps me to remember/recall their meanings. But unfortunately the words 'concrete' and 'discrete' are completely different!

Comment: @linguisticturn Thanks a lot 

Comment: Yes, that's why the best way to learn English is to look up the particular word and then, if there's any relationship to others, that's an added bonus. You can't go the other way and have it work predictably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is/was an English word "**crete**"(n.) meaning a cradle or frame: *it is from the Old French "cretin" = basket*, and probably gives us the word "crate. It is **unrelated** to the "-crete" in concrete and accrete, and is now dialect or obsolete.

In concrete the etymology: *< Latin concrētus, past participle of concrēscĕre to grow together:*

con = together,

Then we have accretion/to accrete *Etymology: < classical Latin accrētiōn-, accrētiō increase < accrēt- , past participial stem of accrēscere accresce v. + -iō -ion suffix*

Thus -crēscĕre to grow; increase.

Thus concrete something that grows together, i.e. solidifies.

There are various prefixes that attach to the "-crete" of other words which each have their own meaning or meanings.

*Italics* = OED